# Can we be given a view of safe and useful configuration data?

Tags: feature-request

Jeff mentions in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22621/dont-forget-you-can-mark-a-question-as-the-answer-reminder-shouldnt-show-up-o/22623#22623) that the amount of time the "Don’t forget you can mark an answer as accepted" appears is *n* days.  This implies that *n* is configurable, and may vary from site to site or time to time.

Right now, we rely on the FAQ and Meta to help us figure out what the current settings are for any particular site.  This seems sub-optimal, since they can change, and the data is obviously available somewhere.

Would it be possible to set up a configuration page where certain configuration data is visible to all, to be used as a reference by users?  Obviously we don't want to dump all the meta-data, just the subset that is safe and useful for users.

I don't know which items are configurable and which are hardcoded, but the following possibilities come to mind:

- The amount of time for which the "Don’t forget you can mark an answer as accepted" appears
- The number of comment flags allowed per day
- The number of post flags allowed per day
- The number of votes allowed per day
- The length of time during which changing a vote is permitted
- The "power" threshholds currently listed explicity in the FAQ.
- Probably more... suggestions?

Comment: I love the idea, I only fear that this opens up people to start saying, "I want to be able to customize all these values!" When they are obscured, it means that Jeff & Co don't have to say "no" as often. But as mentioned, I do love the idea.

Comment: Is it just me or does "Don’t forget you can mark a question as the answer" not make any sense?

Comment: @mmyers: Sometimes the only correct answer *is* another question. ;) But seriously, that doesn't make any sense to me either.

Comment: Copy-n-paste FTL.

Comment: I LOVE THIS IDEA!!! I'm so curious as to how the timing in StackOverflow is configured, and creating such a harmless page that has some of this information would be useful for all.